# No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN (has extras) }

Tags: android, device-admin, android-multiple-users

I'm trying to enable the device administration, so I can create secondary users in Android 9.

First is to send an intent with ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN like this below :

```
                    // Launch the activity to have the user enable our admin.
                Intent deviceAdminIntent = new Intent(DevicePolicyManager.ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN);
                deviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_DEVICE_ADMIN, mDeviceAdminRen);
                deviceAdminIntent.putExtra(DevicePolicyManager.EXTRA_ADD_EXPLANATION,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.device_admin_activation_message));

                startActivityForResult(deviceAdminIntent, REQ_ENABLE_DEVICE_ADMIN);
```

A deviceAdminReceiver must be prior defined in the manifest.xml with the proper intent filter:

```
    <activity android:name=".AuthSessionActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".CreateRenUser"/>
    <receiver android:name=".DeviceAdminRen"
        android:label="@string/renault_device_admin"
        android:description="@string/ren_device_admin_description"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_DEVICE_ADMIN">
        <meta-data android:name="android.app.device_admin"
            android:resource="@xml/device_admin_ren" />
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.app.action.DEVICE_ADMIN_ENABLED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Also the deviceAdminReceiver class is defined :

```
public class DeviceAdminRen extends DeviceAdminReceiver {

.........
```

But then I'm getting the error :

> 03-28 16:44:54.573  7173  7173 E AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.sensory.trulysecureexample/com.sensory.trulysecure.custom.CreateRenaultUser}: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.app.action.ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN (has extras) }
>   03-28 16:44:54.573  7173  7173 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3822)
>   03-28 16:44:54.573  7173  7173 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3854)
>   03-28 16:44:54.573  7173  7173 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.servertransaction.ResumeActivityItem.execute(ResumeActivityIte

My Android application has several activities and fragments but if I understand well, this should be an Android system activity. Also my device has "feature:android.software.device_admin" when listing with "adb shell pm list features"
Is there any limitation in my device preventing to handle the ACTION_ADD_DEVICE_ADMIN intent ??

Note: I followed this Google Android guide https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/admin/device-admin.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What is the content of the constant / variable `mDeviceAdminRen`? That seems to be missing from your code snippet.

It should contain the component name of the device admin component, so in your case `DeviceAdminRen.getComponentName(Context context)`.

Is this the case?

Comment: Yes it is the case :                                                                                                          `mDeviceAdminRent = new ComponentName(getActivity(), DeviceAdminRen.class);`  but it works now as specified in my answer below

Answer (score 0):

As I'm building my application with the Android NDK, I added the LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE build directive in the Makefile of the C++ lib.
gnu-libstdc++/Android.mk:LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true

And it worked !! There is a prompt in Android asking for enabling device administration, and then it becomes easy to create secondary users.